# Azure function regenerating keys after publish

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

Is this expected? Why are my keys being regenerated after each publish? For context, I'm using a precompiled function with a publish profile I downloaded from the Azure portal, and publishing straight through Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Definitely not expected. If you look under `D:\home\data\Functions\secrets` via Kudu Console, do you see those files change when you publish? They shouldn't. Also, is that a v1 or v2 Function App?

Comment: How do you deploy your app ? through ARM template ???

Answer (score 1):

> Is this expected? Why are my keys being regenerated after each publish?

It is not expected.

As  David Ebbo mentioned we could use the [Kudu tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to check the function keys under the **D:\home\data\Functions\secrets\host.json** file.

[image]

If you still get the issue that you mentioned, I recommand that you could create a [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get more help from Azure team.